# What does $f(x) = \infty $ mean?

Tags: real-analysis

I suppose that it means that $f(x)$ is bounded. But Stein says that $f(x)$ is called finite-valued if $-\infty<f(x)<\infty$ for all $x$. It seems to imply that $f$ can equal to $\infty$ at some point $x$. So what does $f(x) = \infty $ mean?

Comment: $f(x)=\infty$ is a "constant function" with a codomain containing $\infty$.

Comment: It doesn't mean that $f(x)$ is bounded, it means that $f(x)$ is equal to the special symbol $\infty$ which is a part of the "extended real number system".

Comment: anything with real numbers but with $\overline{R}$ [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) . Was it a pedagocic claim ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how $\mathrm f(x)=\infty$ when $-\infty < \mathrm f(x) < \infty$?

Comment: So does it mean that the limit of $f(x)$ goes to $\infty$ at that point? @littleO

Comment: No, for that we use the notation $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x$ approaches a particular value. Though the notation $\lim |\text{something}|<\infty$ is sometimes used to mean a finite limit.

Comment: I am familiar with the notion of the extended real line, but I am still confused here. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Okay, I got it. So finite-valued function simply means that it takes value on the real line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Bbb R_E = \Bbb R\cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$ denote the *extended real numbers*.

If $f$ is a function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R_E$, then $f(x)\in \Bbb R_E$ is called *finite-valued* if $f(x) \ne -\infty$ or $f(x) \ne +\infty$. Since $f$ is a function, $f(x) = +\infty$ means that the ordered pair $(x, +\infty) \in f$.